# Geometry Question about Area and surface

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Problem.

According to following diagram, prove  (Area of (MM'N'N)) = 1/3*(Area of ABCD)). We Know that AN = NM = MB and DN' = N'M' = M'C. and quadrilateral ABCD is not and special quadrilateral. diagram:  http://uploads.im/Jh2MF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### edited proof:

As we might observe $S_{ACM}=\dfrac23S_{ACB}$ and $S_{ACN'}=\dfrac23S_{ACD}$, so in total
$$S_{AMCN'}=\frac23S_{ABCD}$$
Now consider $\triangle MCN'$, since $MM'$ is median $S_{MN'M'}=S_{MM'C}$.

Likewise we can conclude $S_{NN'M}=S_{AN'N}$

By adding these two we have:
$$S_{NN'M}+S_{MN'M'}=S_{AN'N}+S_{MM'C}\Rightarrow S_{MM'N'N}=S_{AN'N}+S_{MM'C}\\ \Rightarrow S_{MM'N'N}=\frac12 S_{AMCN'}=\frac12\cdot\frac23S_{ABCD}\quad\checkmark$$

[image]

Comment: How did you conclude sAMM'D = 2/3 sABCD? (I am from Iran, too)

Comment: I did a little mistake in the proof, I'll fix it now.

Comment: I cannot understand why sABCD = sACD + sABD; In the diagram, sABCD = sACD + sABC ,  how did you get sABC = sABD?

Comment: I came up with a new proof, please check it out.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The new proof is right.